# Connecting to a SQL Server instance from another computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, tcp, odbc

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19 and SQL Server 2022 Configuration Manager. I have created an SQL Server instance on my computer which now has a name localhost\MSSQLSERVER01. I am using SQL Server Authentication.

My goal is to create a connection to MSSQLSERVER01 on another computer using ODBC Data Source Administrator and creating a new System DSN data source in order to be able to access the database tables I create on the first computer from the second computer by using for example Microsoft Access.

I have tested the instance by creating a table and connecting through ODBC to it on the local computer and even accessed the mentioned table through Microsoft Access, however I am still unable to connect to MSSQLSERVER01 on another computer. Most of the time I get the SQL Server errors 53 and 17 with the message SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I have done the following things in order to enable the connection:

1. Created a new inbound rule on Windows Firewall to enable connection through port 1433
2. Created a new outbound rule on Windows Firewall to enable connection through port 1433
3. Enabled the protocols TCP/IP and Named Pipes for MSSQLSERVER01 on SQL Server Configuration Manager
4. Configure the TCP/IP protocol properties in SQL Server Configuration Manager such that in the IP Addresses tab in sections IP1 and IPAll set TCP Dynamic ports to 0 and entered 1433 for TCP Port

What else should I configure/change/add/check in order to ensure that I will be able to access the SQL Server instance from other computers?

Comment: Can your client machine ping the server?

Comment: M$ has a tutorial about that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I tried it by "ping localhost\MSSQLSERVER01" and I get nothing and I tried "ping localhost" and get the following ping statistics "Packets: Sent=4, Received=0, Lost=4(100%loss), each time the request timed out.

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER01` is not the default instance name so it wasn't listening on tcp/1433 by default. Do you have another SQL Server instance on the machine that was already listening on tcp/1433? Ports aren't shared so you can only have one instance listening per port. Where you have multiple instance involved you need to open firewall access to udp/1434 for the SQL Browser service (this is used for instance name resolution) together with whatever collection of tcp ports your instances are listening on. And restart the SQL Browser service so that it refreshes its settings for instances and ports.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you wer doing it all on one machine. You don't need TCP protocol enabled, only Shared Memory. And the connection string should have `.\MSSQLSERVER01` or just `.` for a default instance.